# LoopBack: performance issue with relational databases

Tags: node.js, strongloop

In some situations, LoopBack seems to deal in a very inefficient way with relational databases. I've bumped into a performance issue and I was wondering if someone has found a way of working around it.

To demostrate this, I've created a MySQL database with three tables and a simple many-to-many relationship, as shown below.

This is a pretty standard and common situation (which by the way I borrowed straight from LoopBack's documentation).

[image: A simple many-to-may relationship]

Here's how I've populated the tables:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM physician;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Smith    |
|  2 | Johnson  |
|  3 | Williams |
|  4 | Jones    |
+----+----------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM patient;
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Anderson |
|  2 | Jackson  |
|  3 | White    |
|  4 | Roberts  |
|  5 | Lewis    |
|  6 | Clark    |
|  7 | Morgan   |
+----+----------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM appointment;
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
| id | physician_id | patient_id | date       |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
|  6 |            1 |          1 | 2014-06-12 |
|  7 |            1 |          3 | 2014-06-12 |
|  8 |            1 |          5 | 2014-06-12 |
|  9 |            2 |          2 | 2014-06-12 |
| 10 |            2 |          4 | 2014-06-12 |
| 11 |            3 |          7 | 2014-06-12 |
| 12 |            2 |          2 | 2014-06-13 |
+----+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Now, let's say we want to find the list of patients that have an appointment with Dr. Johnson (`physician_id = 2`). There are several sensible ways to achieve this, like:

```
SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id IN( SELECT patient_id FROM appointment WHERE physician_id = 2 )
```

or

```
SELECT patient.* FROM patient JOIN appointment ON patient.id = appointment.patient_id WHERE appointment.physician_id = 2
```

What LoopBack does in the background is totally another story:

```
SELECT `id`, `physician_id`, `patient_id`, `date` FROM `appointment` WHERE `physician_id` = 2 ORDER BY `id`
SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `id` = 2 LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `id` = 4 LIMIT 1
SELECT * FROM `patient` WHERE `id` = 2 LIMIT 1
```

What we see here is that it will first search for all doctor Johnson's appointments (first query) and then search the `patient` table for patients IDs found with the previous query (last 3 queries). Here's the result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jackson"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Roberts"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jackson"
  }
]
```

This looks very inefficient. We can see 4 SQL queries above, which is effectively `1 + n` queries, where `n` is the number of patients! In another words, LoopBack will make MySQL scan the `patient` table as many times as many patients are found in the first query. Obviously this becomes extremely inefficient as the number of records in the patient table grows.

Is there any other way I can achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: On a side note, patient Jackson (`patient_id = 2`) has two appointments with Dr. Johnson (`physician_id = 2`). Notice how LoopBack will ignore this and run the query `SELECT * FROM patient WHERE id = 2` twice, instead of caching the first result. This is without doubt another thing that could be optimized.

Moreover, it seems there's no way one can control whether to get duplicate records or not (i.e. control over whether patient Jackson should be returned twice in the resultset or not).

Comment: you can edit your answer to add in the comment

Comment: Good catch. I'll investigate and work out a fix. I also recommend you to post it to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs.